# Monotone mappings between finite partially ordered sets

Tags: co.combinatorics

How many monotone mappings are there between $P(E)$ (set of all subsets of $E$) and $P(F)$ if $\text{card}(E) = n$ and $\text{card}(F) = m$?

Comment: This is the number $f(m,n) $ of order ideals of the product $C_m\times C_2^n$, where $C_i$ is an $i$-element chain. The number $g(n)$ of order ideals of $C_2^n$ is "Dedekind's problems," http://oeis.org/A000372. It is unlikely that there is a simple formula or even a fast way to compute $g(n)$, so probably also $f(m,n)$. The techniques used to estimate $g(n)$ can be applied to $f(m,n)$.